# Android TextToSpeech in Chrome ARC

Tags: android, text-to-speech, chromium, google-chrome-arc

I'm trying to port my android app to Chrome using ARCWelder.  The TextToSpeech component doesn't seem to work. In one activity I have an indeterminate progress circle waiting until the TTS engine is initialized.  On Chrome, it either spins forever or returns a NullPointerException.  Is TTS not available in Chrome?  Running ChromeOS on a Chromebox.

```
UtteranceProgressListener ttsListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String s) {
        Logg.d("speech started: " + s);
        if (loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDone(String s) {
        Logg.d("speech done: " + s);
        if (s.equals("1")) {
            nextWord();
        } else if (s.equals("2")) {
            CheckLeave();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onError(String s) {
        Logg.e("Text to Speech error speaking: " + s);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    showProgressDialog();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (tts==null) {
        Logg.d("re-initializing TTS");
        tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                            tts.setSpeechRate(.5f + .25f * (Integer)KVDB.GetValue("speechRate",2));
                            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            if (pauseTime != 0) {
                                //Paused. Say nothing.
                            } else if (currentWord == null) {
                                startTime = new ExcelDate();
                                nextWord();
                            } else if (currentWord.length() == 0) {
                                nextWord();
                            } else {
                                reSpeak();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(ttsListener);
    }
    super.onResume();
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loadingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    loadingDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.test_loading_msg));
    loadingDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found, it does look like we don't have any kind of default TTS service provider as part of the ARC package. There is not one provided by the base Android OS at all.

Please feel free to [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) for it.

Comment: I copied this question into a bug report. When you say no default TTS service provider do you mean there is a workaround to access some other TTS engine or there is no way to convert text to speech from ARC at this time?

Comment: You may be able to include another TTS engine by including it in your CRX package (you can include multiple APKs). From what I gathered in looking at the Java code, it should just work, but it is not something we've tested. You would have to deal with any licensing terms for the engine in doing so.

Comment: Lloyd, I'd like to try to implement a workaround like that. I really need to expand access to my app beyond Android if it's to be viable and Chrome just seems like the perfect avenue for that.  Do you know where I can find some guides or help for this? For example how could I incorporate this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilingual-tts-engine/megclklaoidjbomplbhbdgbelkoebbdl

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I need to check my inbox here more often.

Comment: In any case, I took a quick look at the extension you linked to, and it appears to use our cloud TTS engine service, which you can find out about here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/. It looks like an API where you send us a web request containing a string, and we send back the audio data for that string. There's a free trial, but otherwise you would have to pay for it. Otherwise there isn't much guidance I myself can give. Perhaps asking another question here on Stack Overflow would be a good start?